# How to convert a float number to integer by mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How to convert a float number to integer in the form in mvc3?

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CODE)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CODE)
```

Comment: You want the value shown in the text field to be rounded to an integer?

Comment: Just a dumb question here but why don't you save it as an interger if you're going to display it as an integer?  That seems counterproductive.

Answer (score 1):

You could decorate the `CODE` property on your view model with the [`[DisplayFormat]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) attribute which allows you to define the format of the float number when it is displayed in the view:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
public float CODE { get; set; }
```